# Verify path.join is called with certain parameters in mocktail

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, testing, path

I have a function similar to this one below:

```
Future<void> saveFile ({
  required String fileName,
  required Uint8List bytes,
  bool permanent = true,
) async {
  final directory = permanent ? 'permanentFolder' : 'tempFolder';
  final filePath = join(directory, fileName);
  final file = File(filePath);
  await file.create(recursive: true);
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
}
```

I want to write a test on it that verifies that the method `join` from `package:path/path.dart` is being called with the right parameters.

```
await saveFile(fileName: 'name', bytes: []);
verify(() => join('permanentFolder', 'name')).called(1);
await saveFile(fileName: 'name', bytes: [], permanent: false);
verify(() => join('tempFolder', 'name')).called(1);
```

I have not been successful in mocking the `join` function in order for this test to pass.